# Pymunk PinJoint with locked rotation with respect to bodies

Tags: pymunk

I'm trying to create a simple chemistry simulator with atoms (circles) and bonds between them. The problem I'm having is that when atoms 'bond' using a pin joint, the circles rotate independently of the joint. I've tried using more than one pin joint, but the molecules end up oscillating, sometimes wildly, as they stretch and correct themselves. I would appreciate any ideas.

[image: Rotating pin joints]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to create two pinjoints. One from the centres of each of the bodies, and one, very short (0.1), at the contact point of the two bodies. This results in the two bodies (atoms) being very close to each other, but they rotate as a single object. I can set `collide_bodies = False` for both joints, which reduces processing. There is a little movement when the constrained bodies collide with a third body, but overall the solution works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a `RotaryLimitJoint` in addition to the `PinJoint`? It limits the relative rotation between the bodies: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.constraints.html#pymunk.constraints.RotaryLimitJoint

Comment: A GearJoint with a ratio of 1.0 is a similar suggestion. The thing is, if neither of them rotates, then constraining their relative rotation makes no difference.

Comment: Ah, right. Now I understand your question. Depending on your use case another solution would be to combine the two shapes into one body. In this way they will be super stable together.